# How to get rows which are inserted/updated only in Insert/Update step in Pentaho?

Tags: database, pentaho, insert-update, pdi

I'm using Pentaho to insert/update rows to a table with the `Insert/Update step`. The problem is I want to know **which rows are inserted or updated** into my table.

But when I try to create a `Log step` after the `Insert/Update step`, it just **logs all the rows** from the stream no matter if **they've existed** in the table or **newly inserted/updated**.

Is there any way to take the rows that are **inserted/updated to a table only** in the `Insert/Update step`?

[image: logging after Insert/Update step] [image: logging]

Comment: If it is a slow-changing table, then you might want to stop using the insert/update. Also because of speed limitations. Best way is to compare data which is to be insert with data retrieved from original table. You can do this via the "Merge rows diff", which will return a flagfield which rows are identical (unchanged), new (insert), changed (update) and missing (delete). Then handle the cases based on the flagfield. Also logging can then be done per type. 

Best is to set this up once with metadata and from then always reuse the same transformation as a metadata injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Insert/Update step, its not possible to know "which rows are inserted or updated".
But you can use an alternate way to perform insert and update action ; and also know the log status.
You can found sample transformation from [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14BGkvOCpiYGOvw439pnwllQ01u2Jo0Wu/view?usp=sharing)

[image]